# Button to pass an ObservableCollection through EventTrigger

Tags: c#, xaml, button, observablecollection, eventtrigger

I'm struggling to pass my `ObservableCollection<Content>` through a `Button`via the `EventTrigger`.
For now I'm having such code in my xaml:

```
 <Button Name="SendListButton" Content="Go" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="725,737,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" >
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
                    <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding SendContent}"  
                        CommandParameter="{Binding  ElementName=SendListButton}" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </Button>
```

In my `MainViewModel.cs`, I'm having that:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase,IMainViewModel
    {
public ICommand SendContent { get; set; }
public ObservableCollection<Content> ContentsToTransfer { get; set; }

public MainViewModel()
        {
            SendContent = new RelayCommand(OnSendContent);

            ContentsToTransfer = new ObservableCollection<Content>();
        }

private void OnSendContent(ObservableCollection<Content> ContentsToTransfer)
        {
            if (ContentsToTransfer.Any())
            {
                //Code executed by the button. 
            }
        }
```

Can you help me out explainig me how I should pass my ObeservableCollection through the EventTrigger in order to  send its content to a database?

Thx!

Comment: You don't need to send it, it's already in your view model. Remove your `CommandParameter` and get rid of your `OnSendContent` method parameters.

Comment: Good Lord.

This was kinda obvious :/

Once again, thank you @MikeEason :)